# Django-nonrel using ListField containing EmbeddedObjects in the admin

Tags: django, mongodb, django-nonrel

I've been trying hopelessly to get this to work.

I have a model that contains a ListField of EmbeddedObjects, basically it's an Item in an auction that contains a list of bids within it. Typycal MongoDB approach.

I understand that ListField doesn't show up in the admin since it doesn't know what Widget to display, it could be a list of anything. That makes sense.

I've created a fields.py in my app folder and subclassed ListField and I'm now using this in my models.py

My question is:

- How do I keep going from this point onwards until getting a widget on my admin page under the Item section where I can add bids to the Item selected?

Here's my model.py

```
from django.db import models
from djangotoolbox.fields import ListField
from djangotoolbox.fields import EmbeddedModelField
from ebay_clone1.fields import BidsListField

class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=75)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Item(models.Model):
    seller = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    text = models.TextField()
    price = models.FloatField()
    dated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    num_bids = models.IntegerField()
    bids = BidsListField(EmbeddedModelField('Bid'))
    item_type = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title


class Bid(models.Model):
    date_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    value = models.FloatField()
    bidder = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)
```

In my fields.py I have:

```
from django.db import models
from djangotoolbox.fields import ListField
from djangotoolbox.fields import EmbeddedModelField
from django import forms

class BidsListField(ListField):
    def formfield(self, **kwargs):
        return None

class BidListFormField(forms.Field):
    def to_python(self, value):
        if value in validators.EMPTY_VALUES:
            return None
        return value

    def validate(self,value):
        if value == '':
            raise ValidationError('Empty Item String?')
```

Comment: Shouldn't this work already? The code looks perfect. I don't see any question in your post :-)

Comment: Jonas thanks so much for your help mate! Look the code is fine, but I know that I need to somehow subclass forms.Field so that I can tell Django what form/widget to show for my list of embedded bids.

Answer (score 1):

Try this?

```
class BidsListField(ListField):
    def formfield(self, **kwargs):
        return BidListFormField(**kwargs)
```